# Why do I receive Terminal Binding condition in Smack XMPP

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am getting a Terminal binding error when I send a message in between receiving a sequence of messages.

My system 'A' is an android app configured to receive messages
My system 'B' is a standalone java app to send messages.

System B sends a handshake message to to System A that what follows is a specialized kind of messages.

When System A receives the message it sends an acknowledgement that it has received the handshake message and is ready to receive messages.

Now when System B sends specialized messages to System A, the BOSH connection in System A breaks.

Following is the stacktrace for this.

```
<body rid='1882904974501977' sid='977f142470da5f1f2b74af554548c00815de0989' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'></body>
06-09 17:20:47.405 5703-5833/in.ravenapp.raven D/SMACK: RECV (0): <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'/>
06-09 17:20:49.413 5703-5835/in.ravenapp.raven D/SMACK: SENT (0): <body rid='1882904974501978' sid='977f142470da5f1f2b74af554548c00815de0989' xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'></body>
06-09 17:20:49.425 5703-5833/in.ravenapp.raven D/SMACK: RECV (0): <body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind' type='terminate' condition='item-not-found'/>
06-09 17:20:49.429 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/AbstractXMPPConnection: Connection closed with error
                                                                         org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHException: Terminal binding condition encountered: item-not-found  ((1) 'sid' is not valid, (2) 'stream' is not valid, (3) 'rid' is larger than the upper limit of the expected window, (4) connection manager is unable to resend response, (5) 'key' sequence is invalid.)
                                                                             at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.checkForTerminalBindingConditions(BOSHClient.java:1243)
                                                                             at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.processExchange(BOSHClient.java:1065)
                                                                             at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.processMessages(BOSHClient.java:977)
                                                                             at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.access$000(BOSHClient.java:98)
                                                                             at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient$1.run(BOSHClient.java:216)
                                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
06-09 17:20:49.429 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven D/SMACK: XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (0)
06-09 17:20:49.429 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err: org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHException: Terminal binding condition encountered: item-not-found  ((1) 'sid' is not valid, (2) 'stream' is not valid, (3) 'rid' is larger than the upper limit of the expected window, (4) connection manager is unable to resend response, (5) 'key' sequence is invalid.)
06-09 17:20:49.429 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err:     at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.checkForTerminalBindingConditions(BOSHClient.java:1243)
06-09 17:20:49.429 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err:     at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.processExchange(BOSHClient.java:1065)
06-09 17:20:49.429 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err:     at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.processMessages(BOSHClient.java:977)
06-09 17:20:49.433 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err:     at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient.access$000(BOSHClient.java:98)
06-09 17:20:49.433 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err:     at org.igniterealtime.jbosh.BOSHClient$1.run(BOSHClient.java:216)
06-09 17:20:49.433 5703-5832/in.ravenapp.raven W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: What server r u using? I f ejabberd then check if http-bind enabled in config.

Comment: @Kumar The server is ejabberd and http-bind is enabled.

Comment: Please post the code that constructs message stanza and sends to A.